# Asynchronous execution with Page_Load using RegisterAsyncTask

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code snipnet and if executed synchronously it will take some time before the page renders.

I haven't found the code skeleton to make use of Asynchronous to achieve async or is there other way to achieve it so the UI will not stuck executing the lengthy operation. It will be better is the UI first renders and then wait for the operation.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    PageSetup()
    'make the following function execute asynchronously
    LengthyOperation(input)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can load the page on first load to show a loading page and have a hidden button that you click with js that straight away starts to do the longloading on the background

Comment: So process would be like call the client side JS code from page load which will call the server side lengthy operation, isn't that synchronous as well?

Comment: it is.The thing is you don't have a active connection open all the time. once the page life cycle is complete it returns to the client. The server has no way of sending the data later to the client. If you wanna add such a functionality you have to setup a active connection. This can be achieved by implementing SignalR into your project.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with UpdatePanel in hope that this lengthy operations will be executed async and the UI will be partially updated with the content.

But LoadUpdatePanels never gets called.

Client side:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpCheckout" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblWait" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Please wait..."></asp:Label>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" DataSourceID="xmlDS">
            <ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="xmlDS" runat="server" CacheDuration="1" XPath="//something"></asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:Button ID="hiddenAsyncTrigger" runat="server" Text="AsyncUpdate" style="display:none;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="hiddenAsyncTrigger" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server side:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

    If Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.Page.GetType, "LoadUpdate") Then     
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page.GetType, "LoadUpdate", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(hiddenAsyncTrigger, String.Empty))
    End If
End Sub 

Sub LoadUpdatePanels(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles hiddenAsyncTrigger.Click

    'lengthy operations

    lblWait.Text = "Content is now loaded."
End Sub
```